# Self-Adjoint Transformation in Visualization

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Self-adjoint transformations obey $\langle T v, w\rangle=\langle v, T w\rangle$

What is a simple example and visualization of a self-adjoint matrix where everything is on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? The book I am using is very algebraic and does not present any examples.

Comment: It's a stretch/squeeze in one direction and also in the perpendicular direction.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? If $w$ is a fixed vector, then we take some $v$ to $Tv$ and this dot product happens to be the same if we took $w$ to $Tw$ instead. So I am guessing the magnitude and angle shift from $v$ to $Tv$ has to be made up by $w$ to $Tw$. But how ?

Comment: Self-adjoint maps in spaces with positive-definire inner products are diagonalizable. Do you know how to interprete the action of a diagonal matrix? That's it (up to change of basis).

Answer (score 0):

Theorem : $T : V \longrightarrow V$ is a self-adjoint operator if, and only if, its matrix relative to a (and therefore to any) orthonormal basis $B = \lbrace v_{1}, \cdots, v_{n} \rbrace \subset V$ is a symmetric matrix.

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a linear operator defined by: $T(x,y) = (x, 2y)$

So, for all $v = (x,y)$, we have:

1) $\langle e_{1}, T^{*}v \rangle = \langle Te_{1}, v \rangle = \langle e_{1}, v \rangle = x$

2) $\langle e_{2}, T^{*}v \rangle = \langle Te_{2}, v \rangle = \langle 2e_{2}, v \rangle = 2y$

From the above theorem, we have: $T^{*} = T$.